# Database Model Best practices - i.e Survey

Tags: database, django

having this two classes I always have a doubt of which is the best practice "linking" them ( if any)

Question

```
class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField('Question',max_length=120)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    opens = models.DateTimeField()
    closes = models.DateTimeField()
```

Answer

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    text =  models.CharField('Answer',max_length=120)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**Wrong -** I can add this line to Answer **(this was a copy / paste error):**

```
answers = models.ForeignKey(Answer)
```

**Edit:**

```
answers = models.ManyToManyField(Answer)
```

I can add this line to Answer:

```
question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

I would like to know if it really doesn't matter or I should consider different aspects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Question: 
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer)
```

> "This particular question has only one possible answer".

---

```
class Answer: 
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

> "This answer belongs to one particular question only, but that question might have multiple separate answers"

---

```
class Answer:
    question = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
```

> "This particular answer is an answer to multiple questions. So questions can have multiple separate answers"

---

```
class Question:
    answers = modes.ManyToManyField(Answer)
```

> "This question has multiple distinct answers. Also answers can belong to multiple questions." [**Best approach**]

---

An question has to have answers. You don't make an answer (usually) to answer multiple questions, instead, an answer answers one particular question, but there may be multiple answers (from different users for example). Therefore I'd pick 4 .

Answer (score 1):

```
answers = models.ForeignKey(Answer)

question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

These are not equivalent. The first (assuming you meant the first should be on `Question` will mean that a question has only one answer but an answer has more than one question - guessing this is not what you want.

The second will mean that an answer has a single question and that questions will have more than one answer which is presumably what you want. By default this will add an answer_set field to Question containing all of a questions answers.

Comment: Can I access to the answer set from a question like an attribute? like question.answer_set?

Comment: @XaviColomer Yep, question.answer_set will be a query set you can use. I.e. question.answer_set.all() will return all answers for that question. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

Comment: I edited the question to fix a little error. My question is, there is any performance issues? Is any solution better than the other ( for lazy loading, etc... ) Thanks!

Comment: @XaviColomer See Timmy O'Mahony's answer but the many to many and many to one have different behaviour the "better" solution will be the one that fits your needs. It all really boils down to whether you want the same answer to be used in multiple questions. For me I would use the ForeignKey link but your mileage may vary.